# Use JSOM to get unique permissions for a folder in document library

Tags: javascript, document-library, permissions, jsom, folder

I would like to be able to retrieve the permissions for specific folders in a document library via JSOM. Specifically, I would like to be able to use JS to determine if the active folder that the user has navigated to (ie: Documents/SubFolder) is accessible by "everyone" or not.

I have figured out to how pull the folder path from the URL query string and I can access the folder object using *getFolderByServerRelativeUrl*; however, I am having difficulty figuring out how to list the permissions for that folder. I have found other questions that address breaking permissions and assigning new permissions, but nothing that identifies how to get the current permissions. From my research, I was thinking I may need to use *hasPermissions* to get what I wanted, but I haven't had any luck with that yet.

Current Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentURL = window.location.search;
var urlQuery = currentURL.toString();
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
getFolderPermissions(currentURL);
});

function getFolderPermissions(folderPath) {
var cleanFolderPath = decodeURIComponent(folderPath.split("=")[1].split("&")[0]);
var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(cleanFolderPath);
var currentFolderAssignments = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(cleanFolderPath).get_listItemAllFields().get_effectiveBasePermissions();
clientContext.load(currentFolderAssignments, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {    
        console.log(currentFolderAssignments);  
    }
    , Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnItemQueryFailed)
);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little bit old... but to see *Everyone* permissions on folder, you can do like this:

```
var login = "c:0(.s|true"; //Everyone login
var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(cleanFolderPath);
var effectivePermissions = folder.get_listItemAllFields().getUserEffectivePermissions(login);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
       var canRead = effectivePermissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems);
   }),
   Function.createDelegate(this, errorCallback)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be done on the client side using: SP.ListItem.get_effectiveBasePermissions()

See this link for more info: https://andrewwburns.com/2012/02/29/check-permissions-in-javascript-client-object-model/

Comment: Unfortunately _effectiveBasePermissions_ is not available for Folders in my SharePoint library. After some additional research it looks like I may be able to find what I need via  _.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath).get_listItemAllFields().get_roleAssignments().getMember_. I'm not there yet, but I think I'm getting closer.

Comment: Ok, did a little more digging and it looks like I should be able to get to _EffectiveBasePermissions_ via _web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(cleanFolderPath).get_listItemAllFields().get_effectiveBasePermissions()_; however, every time I try to do this I get an error stating "The property or field 'EffectiveBasePermissions' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Comment: Are you running the javascript as a function that runs following an event?? Or are you running the function as the page loads??

Comment: I run it as a function inside _$(document).ready()_

Comment: Ok, figured out how to access _get_effectiveBasePermissions_; however, so far I have only figured out how to check permission levels for current / logged in user. What I would like to do is determine if current folder is available to everyone (all authenticated users) or not... is this possible with _get_effectiveBasePermissions_ or maybe with _get_roleAssignments_?

Comment: you should ensure that there sharepoint sp.js has finished loading before running your scripts - try putting this line before the main function is called:
{ ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunction, "sp.js");});